# Unable to add the ipp network printer to cup server

Tags: cups, cups4j

I would like to add the network printer to cups server using http call ( printer_host_name, port).

I couldn't find the way to add the printer to cupserver from cups api documentation.

Please share the cup api which allows to add ipp network printer into cups and share the different approaches to connect the printer.

Currently, I have connecting the cup server with cups4j library through java.

**`https://github.com/harwey/cups4j/issues/68 https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups/issues/514 https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-client-kotlin/issues/10`**

Additional Links :
https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups/issues/514
https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups/issues/516

Thanks

Currently, I have connecting the cup server with cups4j library through java..

Comment: CupsClient of library "ipp-client" has been updated to support setting up ipp network printers: setupIppEverywherePrinter(printerName,URI.create("ipp://myprinter:631/ipp/print"),"MyInfo","MyLocation")